# Нужна ли тут запятая перед КАК?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, как

Я буду ходить **как** модель.
Я научу тебя ходить **как** я.
Любовь **как** пламя.

Нужна ли тут запятая и почему?

Answer (score 1):

Не нужна. Запятая отделяет часть предложения, которую можно безвредно опустить. В Ваших примерах изначальный смысл фразы без "как..." исчез бы.

Answer (score 0):

***1) Я буду ходить как модЕль.***

Сравнительный оборот в роли необособленного обстоятельства образа действия (ходить по-особенному). Ударение переходит на оборот.

2) ***Я научу тебя ходИть,  как (хожу) я.***

Обособленный сравнительный оборот. Ударение ставится и на глагол, и на оборот, делается пауза.

3)  ***Любовь как пламя.*** Оборот в роли именной части сказуемого.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

Обычно тире не ставится: 2) если в роли связки выступают сравнительные союзы как, будто, словно, точно, вроде как, всё равно что и т. п.: Речи как речи (Фурм.); Звёзды будто мелкие алмазы; Облака словно сказочные чудовища; **Сегодня небо точно море.**